# диапазон времени от 4 дня до 12 ночи

Tags: php, дата, время, проверка

сделал проверку по интервалу времени, но не могу решить одну загвоздку.

Я накидал код , но не знаю как вывести на воскресенье, что завтрак будет в 12:00
т.е если в воскресное утро на часах 10:00 то нужно вывести open at 12:00

1. понедельник-четверг 4:00-10:00
2. пятница-нерабочий
3. Суббота 4:00-12:00
4. Воскресный BRUCH 12:00-3:00
5. Воскресный DINNER 4:00 -10:00

```html
<span class="mainHeader__open mainHeader__size">                 

    <?php 
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tashkent');
        $d = new DateTime;
        $day = $d->format('N');
        $hour = $d->format('H');
        $ferialStart = 16;
        $ferialEnd = 22;
        $saturdayEnd = 24;
        $brunchStart = 12;
        $brunchEnd = 15;
        $dinnerStart = 16;
        $dinnerEnd = 22;
    ?>  
    <?php if(($day == 1 || $day == 2 || $day == 3 || $day == 4) && ($hour >= $ferialStart && $hour < $ferialEnd)): ?>
        Open Now
        <span class="mainHeader__timeToClose mainHeader__size">Closed at 22:00 PM </span>
    <?php elseif($day == 5): ?>
        <span class="closed">Closed</span>
        <span class="mainHeader__timeToClose mainHeader__size">open at 4:00 </span>
    <?php elseif(($day == 6) && ($hour >= ferialStart && $hour < $saturdayEnd)): ?>
        Open Now
        <span class="mainHeader__timeToClose mainHeader__size">Closed at 22:00 PM </span>
    <?php elseif(($day == 7) && ($hour >= $brunchStart && $hour <= $brunchEnd)): ?>
        Open Now - SUNDAY BRUCH
    <?php elseif(($day == 7) && ($hour >= $dinnerStart  && $hour < $dinnerEnd)): ?>
        Open Now - SUNDAY DINNER
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="closed">Closed</span>
        <span class="mainHeader__timeToClose mainHeader__size">open at 4:00 am</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
 </span>
```

[image: вид вывода]

Answer (score 0):

Понедельник - 0.

Воскресенье - 6.

Answer (score 0):

решил проблему доп проверкой, где $hour = $d->format('H') и $saturdayEnd = 24(00:00);
 `elseif(($day == 6) && ($hour <= $saturdayEnd)):
  то открывается в 12:00`